# How create a Bundle In React using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I want to export a Component in a bundle to access it from an index.html that anyone can create and import that js library.

I was reading two tutorials, but I have not understood very well.

I would be grateful if someone explained it to me step by step what exactly I should do or I would upload a scheme of how it should be on github.

I've never used babel and create a bundle.

Should I create a project with create-react-app ??

Please help me.

This is are two tutorials:

https://www.robinwieruch.de/webpack-advanced-setup-tutorial/

https://www.robinwieruch.de/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup/#babel-react-setup

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

// this dependeny is uploaded on my private verdaccio server
import { MapActions, LayerActions } from '@customdependency/map-module';

class APIService extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.logged = (this.props.userLogged && this.props.userLogged.logged) ? true : false;
        this.interval = undefined;
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.interval = undefined;
    };

    getUserLayers = () => {
        if (!this.logged) return null;
        const userlayers = this.props.layers.filter(l => l.name).map(l => {
            return { id: l.id, name: l.name, order: l.order };
        });
        return userlayers;
    };

    getVisibilityLayerById = (id) => {
        if (!this.logged) return null;
        let index = this.props.layers.findIndex(l => l.id === id);
        if (index === -1) return null;
        return (this.props.layers[index] && this.props.layers[index].layout && this.props.layers[index].layout.visibility) ? this.props.layers[index].layout.visibility : null;
    };

    getVisibilityLayerByOrder = (order) => {
        if (!this.logged) return null;
        let index = this.props.layers.findIndex(l => l.order === order);
        if (index === -1) return null;
        return (this.props.layers[index] && this.props.layers[index].layout && this.props.layers[index].layout.visibility) ? this.props.layers[index].layout.visibility : null;
    };

    changeVisibilityLayerById = (id) => {
        if (!this.logged) return null;
        let index = this.props.layers.findIndex(l => l.id === id);
        if (index === -1) return null;
        let layer = this.props.layers[index];
        this.props.changeLayerVisibility(layer);
    };

    changeVisibilityLayerByOrder = (order) => {
        if (!this.logged) return null;
        let index = this.props.layers.findIndex(l => l.order === order);
        if (index === -1) return null;
        let layer = this.props.layers[index];
        this.props.changeLayerVisibility(layer);
    };

    changeLayerVisibilityWithIntervalById = (id, interval) => {
        if (!this.logged) return null;
        setInterval( () => {
            this.changeVisibilityLayerById(id);
        }, interval);
    };

    changeLayerVisibilityWithIntervalByOrder = (order, interval) => {
        if (!this.logged) return null;
        setInterval( () => {
            this.changeVisibilityLayerByOrder(order);
        }, interval);
    };

    getCenter = () => {
        if (!this.logged) return null;
        let properties = (this.props.properties !== null) ? Object.assign({}, this.props.properties) : null;
        let hasCenter = (properties !== null && Object.keys(properties).filter(p => p === "center")) ? true : false;
        let hasLatAndLong = (hasCenter) ? Object.keys(properties.center).filter(c => c === 'latitude' || c === 'longitude') : null;
        let center = (hasLatAndLong !== null && hasLatAndLong.length === 2) ? true : false;
        return (center) ? properties.center : null;
    };

    setCenter = (latitude, longitude) => {
        if (!this.logged) return null;
        if ( isNaN(latitude) || isNaN(longitude) ) return null;
        this.props.setCenter({ latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude });
    };

    getZoom = () => {
        if (!this.logged) return null;
        let properties = (this.props.properties !== null) ? Object.assign({}, this.props.properties) : null;
        let hasZoom = (properties !== null && Object.keys(properties).filter(p => p === "zoom")) ? true : false;
        return (hasZoom !== null) ? properties.zoom : null;
    };

    setZoom = (zoom) => {
        if (!this.logged) return null;
        let checkedZoom;
        if (Array.isArray(zoom)) checkedZoom = zoom;
        else checkedZoom = [zoom];
        this.props.setZoom(checkedZoom);
    };

    render() { return null };
}

function selectStateApp(state) {
    return {
        userLogged: state.auth.userLogged,
        layers: state.maplayers.mapGLlayers,
        properties: state.map.properties,
    };
}

export default compose(withTranslation('axis'), connect(
    selectStateApp,
    dispatch => ({
        changeLayerVisibility: (layer) => LayerActions.changeLayerVisibility(layer)(dispatch),
        setCenter: (center) => MapActions.setCenter(center)(dispatch),
        setZoom: (zoom) => MapActions.setZoom(zoom)(dispatch),
        setProperties: (properties) => MapActions.setProperties(properties)(dispatch),
    })
))(APIService);
```